# Django link two apps

Tags: django, routes, project

im currently facing the problem that i want to call a view from another app (accounts app which holds the user model) within my main app (a blog app).

this is the error i get:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (username) specified for User
```

urls.py

```
...
from quickblog import views as core_views
from accounts import views as views_accounts

...
url(r'^myaccount/$', views_accounts.view_profile, name='myaccount'),
```

views.py (accounts app):

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse

from accounts.forms import (
    RegistrationForm,
    EditProfileForm
)

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('accounts:home'))
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()

        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'reg_form.html', args)


def view_profile(request, pk=None):
    if pk:
        user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    else:
        user = request.user
    args = {'user': user}
    return render(request, 'profile.html', args)


def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('accounts:view_profile'))
    else:
        form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'edit_profile.html', args)


def change_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
            return redirect(reverse('accounts:view_profile'))
        else:
            return redirect(reverse('accounts:change_password'))
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)

        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'change_password.html', args)
```

This is my first django app, is there maybe anything i need to know about linking two apps within one project?

thanks

Comment: This error doesn't appear to have anything at all to do with linking apps. What makes you think it does?

Comment: Did you make migrations? Show your views.py. This error seems not to be linked with the urls.py

Comment: @Wariored updated.